# ST_length error on geometrycollections in HANA

Tags: gis, hana

I am trying to perform the following query. I want to find the length of the segments that are found when intersecting the village polygons with the respective line segments

```
select D.VILLAGE_RJID, A.CITYNAME,A.Scope_Category,A.Phase, A.NETWORKTYPE, A.NETWORKCATEGORY, A.LINK_ID, A.SPAN_ID, A.INTRACITY_LINK_ID, 
    round(sum(d.shape.ST_Intersection(a.shape).st_length())/1000,2) as Planned(Km)",
    round(sum(d.shape.ST_Intersection(b.shape).st_length())/1000,2) as ConstrComp(Km)",
    round(sum(d.shape.ST_Intersection(c.shape).st_length())/1000,2) as "AsBuilt(Km)",
    d.shape.ST_Intersection(a.shape) as shape
from "GIS_USER"."PLANNEDROUTE" A, "GIS_USER"."R4G_OSPROUTE" B, "GIS_USER"."CONSTRUCTIONCOMPSTATUS" C, "GIS_USER".VILLAGE d
WHERE A.NETWORKCATEGORY||A.LINK_ID||A.SPAN_ID||A.INTRACITY_LINK_ID = B.NETWORKCATEGORY||B.LINK_ID||B.SPAN_ID||B.INTRACITY_LINK_ID
    AND A.NETWORKCATEGORY||A.LINK_ID||A.SPAN_ID||A.INTRACITY_LINK_ID = C.NETWORK_CATEGORY||C.LINK_ID||C.SPAN_ID||C.INTRACITY_LINK_ID
    AND d.shape.ST_Intersects(a.shape)=1
group by D.VILLAGE_RJID, A.CITYNAME,A.Scope_Category,A.Phase,A.NETWORKTYPE, A.NETWORKCATEGORY, A.LINK_ID, A.SPAN_ID, A.INTRACITY_LINK_ID,d.shape.ST_Intersection(a.shape);
```

However I am getting an error stating that `ST_Length` is not supported in geometrycollection. (I understand geometrycollection is a collection of geometries and `St_length` would not work on a point geometry if it is present)

Is there a way to resolve this issue in  SAP HANA? Gladly would appreciate your help or any suggestions.

Comment: What ST_-type is stored in your "shape" column? ST_GEOMETRYCOLLECTION?
If so, then you have to address the specific geometry you want to work with via `shape..ST_GeometryN(x)` where x is the index of the geometry.

Also: DON'T use concatenation for your join condition. That's just plain wrong. Instead use the multi column condition: 
`(A.NETWORKCATEGORY, A.LINK_ID, A.SPAN_ID, A.INTRACITY_LINK_ID) = (B.NETWORKCATEGORY, B.LINK_ID, B.SPAN_ID, B.INTRACITY_LINK_ID)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion.
I was getting ST_Geometrycollection, St_Point and ST_Linestring in multiple rows of the result table. SO I used ST_geometryType to filter out only those columns having ST_LineString and ST_MultiLineString types and running the ST_Length () query,  but it is  taking a long time to run the query, it is not giving the above error.